# How to upload website created by AdonisJs on vps.hudsonvalleyhost.com?

Tags: file-upload, vps, adonis.js

I have a files of a website created using the AdonisJs by a friend and i want to upload it on [enter link description here](https://vps.hudsonvalleyhost.com:5656/login.php) .
Basically when i run filezilla on laptop it shows inside server the Root file . So my question is:
In which direction should i upload the files?

Comment: Your external link is not working, better to give a self-contained description here (upload to another server/provider).

Comment: sorry this is the link
https://vps.hudsonvalleyhost.com:5656/login.php

Comment: This is not a programming question. In my opinion you should delete it here and ask at https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the files on website S, the target server for your upload is T and your local workstation is W. Then you can do it in two steps:

1. Download it from S to W.
2. Upload it from W to T.

Comment: The website has been programmed by someone else
i just have the files of the website and i want to upload it on the host
in the host there's the root file . so in which direction should i upload the website files which is right now on my laptop?

Comment: Whoever programmed it is not relevant. You first have to get the files from S and then put them to T. If you don't have access to one of the server than it's not only a problem of file trandfer direction.

Comment: Am little bit not familiar with this host .
So usually on other host there's a main direction where you have to upload your website files there and once someone type your domain name the website start running .
on this host i don't know where's the main direction . so if i uploaded the website files in the root file i don't know if it will work when someone type the domain name
Ths isa picture from fillzila when i login to the host
it shows the root file and inside it some other files
https://i.imgur.com/J4cYsNd.png
here are the website files on my laptop
https://i.imgur.com/JtfuBWQ.png